# How to add 'main/src/.../messages.properties' file to ShrinkWrap WebArchive?

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I have the following files in a project:

```
com/example/module/Messages.java
com/example/module/messages.properties
```

Using `ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war").addPackages(true, "com.example.module")` only adds `Messages.java` to the generated archive. How can I add `messages.properties`?

Thanks.

**Edit.**

I am using `addAsResource` now but it only works for files that are under `test/resources` folder. How can I make it work with files under `main/src`? Is there any maven configuration for that?

The goal is to not duplicate files. Right now I have one file under `main/src` and a duplicate under `test\resources`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally added this configuration to my POM:

```xml
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources/</directory>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```

Then I added the properties file with:

```java
.addAsResource("com/example/module/messages.properties")
```

Now Maven copies my `messages.properties` to the directory `target/test-classes`. Therefore ShrinkWrap will find it in the classpath.

Comment: The trick is to add resource as a File `addAsResource(new File("src/main/foobar.properties"), "foobar.properties"))`. Otherwise it must exist in the classpath - see `org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.container.ContainerBase.fileFromResource(String resourceName)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `addAsResource` method to add the file.  The method is defined here: https://github.com/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/api/container/ResourceContainer.java#L86

Comment: I am using `asAsResource` now but it only works for files that are under `test/resources` folder. Do you know how to make it work with files under `main\src`? Is there any maven configuration that can help me?

Comment: Yes, just use the full path.  `.addAsResource("src/main/foobar.properties","foobar.properties")`

Comment: I've tried this before but it didn't work. I had to add `src/main` as a test resource.

Comment: @rubenlop88 - the trick is to add resource as a File  `addAsResource(new File("src/main/foobar.properties"), "foobar.properties"))`

Answer (score 2):

The trick in this case is to add resource as a File:

`addAsResource(new File("src/main/foobar.properties"), "foobar.properties"))`.

Otherwise it must exist in the classpath - see `org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.container.ContainerBase.fileFromResource(String resourceName)`.