# Replace .properties resource in Arquillian

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

I'm using **Arquillian, version 1.4.1.Final**, for testing and I need to use a different .properties file in the test environment, to have a different configuration as in production.

So far I tried to add it as resource in my WebArchive (as stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577352/how-to-add-main-src-messages-properties-file-to-shrinkwrap-webarchive)) like this:

```
WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class)
                .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                .importBuildOutput()
                .as(WebArchive.class);

webArchive = webArchive.addAsResource("test-file.properties");
```

But the test fails with the following error:

```
RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive .createWar()
```

I also tried to delete the current file before adding the new one `webArchive.delete(/path/to/file)`, but ends up throwing the same exception.

Is there any way to do this similar to `webArchive.deleteClass()` and `webArchive.addClass()`?